# Using Strapi CMS as an admin panel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, laravel, strapi

Our team has little experience with Strapi CMS. We want to know if its possible to utilise  Strapi simply as a backend Admin panel / React admin framework to serve a Laravel PHP backend?

Having a backend admin panel framework would save us allot of time. Is it possible to access the MySQL Strapi models through Laravel?

Comment: ofcourse you can

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you couldn't use the admin panel to create the necessary relations and tables for your DB and then directly tap into those entries via your own defined models within Laravel, if that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

For this kind of need, I suggest you use an Admin Dashboard manager that will be plugged into your Laravel application database.
Something like Forest Admin for example.